# Одобрено вам или вамИ?

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи

Как правильно: «Одобрено **вам** или вам**и**»?

Answer (score 2):

Одобрено вами - творительный падеж, обозначает производителя действия. Вы одобрили - одобрено вами.

Comment: Greatest Sophia
как меня писать эту sentence;"могли вы сообщить  предварительный план действии одобрено вам"

Comment: "Вы могли бы сообщить план действия, одобренного Вами" (и ранее представленного Вам).

Если это, конечно, не новогодняя шутка с Вашей стороны.